# Find the height of a square "pyramid" *General Form*

Tags: geometry, 3d

This is the general shape of a pyramid stacked using squares. For example, the first layer would have 1 sphere, the second layer would have 4, and each layer would have $n^2$ spheres. I want to know a general formula of the height with $n$ layers expressed with $r$ as a function of $h_n(r)$.

I've made to $n=2$ so far, but I can't figure out the height beyond $2$ or even the general form.

*My progress:*

Obviously, we know that the height if it's 1 layer would be $2r$, or $h_1(r)=2r$.

It is also relatively easy if we have $2$ layers.[image]
We can construct a pyramid by connecting the $5$ centers. Using Pythagorean theorem, we can know that the middle portion is $\sqrt{2}r$. Therefore, the total height would be $h_2(r)=r(2+\sqrt{2})$

I start to struggle with $3$ layers. Please help me solving for that as well as a general form. Hopefully this version is more detailed and well-written question.

Comment: Well done @CellSecret. Your question now merits more attention, and has improved a lot from its previous state. See, making sure that every question of yours is like this will be an extremely beneficial attitude to have on the site : it leads to greater attention, better focus on the question, and better answers. I am sure your next question will be better.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks! I will try my best on every question. :) But please put your suggestions if my questions need to be improved. For this one, I just got randomly downvoted until someone said that I should revise it.

Comment: Good point, @CellSecret. I admit I did not explain my downvote, and I'm sorry about that. The reason is for that is because I visit about 175 questions like this everyday, trying to help improve each of them. Sometimes I'm able to leave a comment, but sometimes I can only downvote, sometimes only close. I wish I could do more, but I have time constraints, and very few people do my job for me. So thanks very much for taking the message from the answer below and improving your question, and I promise I'll give you suggestions on your next questions if and when I see them. (+1 to the question)

Comment: Thanks :) The process of writing the problem actually helped me into thinking it deeper too!

Comment: Great. That would be one of the advantage points of having you think through your problem and frame it better. Have a good day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a model with $r=1$ for simplicity,
let $A$ be the center of the upper circle
and $B,C,D,E$ be the centers of the underlying four circles.
These points represent a pyramid with
$|AB|=|AC|=|AD|=|AE|=|BC|=|CD|=|DE|=|EB|=2$.

[image]

The base $BCDE$ of the pyramid is a $2\times2$ square,
all the distances from $B,C,D,E$ to the center of the square are equal to $\sqrt2$,
and obviously, the height $|AO|=\sqrt2$.
Accounting for the radii of the balls on the top and the bottom,
the height of two layers of spheres in such an arrangement
must be $|AO|+2=2+\sqrt2$. Adding one layer below, we just need to add $\sqrt2$,
so the total height of the pyramid of 14 balls is $2+2\sqrt2$,
and for the balls of radius $r$ it would be $2(1+\sqrt2)\,r$.

---

**Edit**

The total height of the pyramid
of $n$ layers of balls
with $n\times n$ balls on the bottom layer
would then be

\begin{align} 
h_n(r) &= (2+\sqrt2 (n-1))\,r 
,\\
h_1&=2
,\\
h_2&=(2+\sqrt2)\,r
,\\
h_3&=(2+2\sqrt2)\,r
,\\
h_4&=(2+3\sqrt2)\,r
,\\
h_5&=(2+4\sqrt2)\,r
,\\
&\cdots
\end{align}

This is a diagonal cross-section of the 14-balls pyramid:

[image]

Comment: It would be super-duper wonderful if you consider reading the [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) on meta.math.se.  Have a wonderful day!

Comment: @g.kov I beg your pardon, you were right, I was wrong. I erase my erroneous remark. I thought it was an FCC "crystal  structure" instead of a HCP structure... Besides [+1}, nice graphics.

Comment: @Jean Marie:  Thanks, it's OK. 
The images were prepared using
[Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Mine is with Matlab... less easy to manipulate.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I was trying to draw a ton of pyramids connecting the center. I would never try to draw out a cross section lol. That makes sense! (+1 and approved)


By the way I use [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/3d?lang=en) to make my diagrams.

Comment: I looked at these 14 balls in interactive 3d webgl from all possible angles, 
trying to figure out how it would be better to illustrate it.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Spheres stacked in this way can be considered as part of a HCP (Hexagonal Closed Packed) crystal structure. This kind of sphere packing has well known properties, in particular the fact that successive parallel planes passing through the centers of spheres of a given level are distant one from the other by distance

$$d=\sqrt{2}r \ \ \ \text{where r is the common radii of spheres}$$

(see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres))

Therefore, adding an initial $r$ and a final $r$ for the bottom and for the top, the answer is:

$$2d+2r=2r\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)$$

Remark: A well-written [document](https://www.mathematicalwhetstones.com/uploads/5/4/9/9/54991295/blog_2_sir_walter_raleighs_cannon_balls.pdf) about these issues.

Comment: So $2r(1+\sqrt{2})$ is just the case with $3$ layers? And we have to add $d$ for every layer added right? Therefore, $h(n)=(n-1)d+2r$?

Comment: That's write. I forgot to say it.

Comment: This diagram is a bit hard to see than the one above. Still great explanation though! (+1)

Comment: I have attempted to play on transparency (initial pyramid in grey)... but I should choose different colors.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the balls in each layer are arranged in a square lattice and neighbours are touching.  If four balls are at the corners of a square, figure out how high a ball must be over the centre of the square so that the distance from the four balls is twice the radius.